# Universal TextField for TableView

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I want to use a class `TextField` for a `TableCell` in JavaFX, which should be used universally.

I can display the data in TableView, however, the changes do not arrive in the controller and are not being saved in the data class.

I want to be able to control the behavior from the TableView while interfacing with my class correctly and storing the data.

At the moment I can see the values from the data class in TableView and edit them according to the setting in the class, however, I can't get the data into the data class in the controller.

Here is my approach so far:

Controller

```java
columnCourse.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("CourseName"));
columnCourse.setCellFactory(i -> new CellClassTextFieldString(columnCourse, 20));
columnCourse.setOnEditCommit(e -> { System.out.println("Commit in Controller ");; });
```

TextFieldClass

```java
public class CellClassTextFieldString<T> extends TableCell<T, String> {
    
    private final TextField textField;
    private final int maxLen;
    
    public  CellClassTextFieldString(TableColumn<T, String> stringCol, Integer maxLen) {   

        this.textField = new TextField();
        this.maxLen = maxLen;
        
        
        this.textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(new StringConverter<String>() {
            
            @Override
            public String toString(String object) {
                if(object == null) return "";
                
                if (object.length() > maxLen) {
                    return object.substring(0, maxLen);
                } else {
                    return object;
                }
                
            }

            @Override
            public String fromString(String string) {
               if(string == null) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    if (string.length() > maxLen) {
                        return string.substring(0,maxLen);
                    } else {
                        return string;
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }));
        
        
       
    editableProperty().bind(stringCol.editableProperty());
    
        
        
    contentDisplayProperty().bind(Bindings
        .when(editableProperty())
                .then(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY)
                .otherwise(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY)
    );           
        
        setListener () ;

    }   
    
    
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String strInput, boolean empty) {
        System.out.println("updateItem");
    super.updateItem(strInput, empty);
        
    if(empty) {
            
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
            
    } else {
            
        
        this.textField.setText(strInput);       
        setGraphic(this.textField);
            
        if(strInput == null) {
        setText("");
        } else {
        setText(strInput);
        }
    }   
    } 
 
    
    private void setListener () {

        this.textField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {       
        if(newValue) {
                System.out.println("get focus");       
        } else {
                System.out.println("lost focus");
                commitEdit(textField.getText());
                
            }
    });
        
        this.textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        

                System.out.println("comit : " + newValue + "isEditing : " + isEditing());
                if (newValue.length() > maxLen) {
                    textField.setText(oldValue);
                }
    });   
        
        
        this.textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            
            @Override public void handle(KeyEvent evt) {
                
                if (KeyCode.ESCAPE == evt.getCode()) {
                    System.out.println("cancel edit");
                    cancelEdit();
                }
                
                if (KeyCode.ENTER == evt.getCode() || KeyCode.TAB == evt.getCode() ) {
                    System.out.println("commit edit");
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue i can clearly notice is with the binding of contentDisplayProperty. Is it that you want the textField only when you edit? if that is the case you need to bind with the readonly editing property instead of editable property.

```
contentDisplayProperty().bind(Bindings
                    .when(editingProperty())
                    .then(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY)
                    .otherwise(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY)
            );
```

Below is the modified cell implementation that can work. (atleast it works for me :-))

```
class CellClassTextFieldString<T> extends TableCell<T, String> {
        private TextField textField;
        private final int maxLen;

        public CellClassTextFieldString(TableColumn<T, String> stringCol, Integer maxLen) {
            this.maxLen = maxLen;
            editableProperty().bind(stringCol.editableProperty());
            contentDisplayProperty().bind(Bindings
                    .when(editingProperty())
                    .then(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY)
                    .otherwise(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY)
            );
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String strInput, boolean empty) {
            System.out.println("updateItem");
            super.updateItem(strInput, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getItem());
                    }
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(getItem());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public final void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(getItem());
        }

        @Override
        public final void commitEdit(final String newValue) {
            super.commitEdit(newValue);
        }

         @Override
        public final void startEdit() {
             super.startEdit();
             if (textField == null) {
                 createTextField();
             }
             setGraphic(textField);
             textField.setText(getItem());
             textField.selectAll();
             textField.requestFocus();
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            this.textField = new TextField();
            this.textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(new StringConverter<String>() {
                @Override
                public String toString(String object) {
                    if (object == null) return "";

                    if (object.length() > maxLen) {
                        return object.substring(0, maxLen);
                    } else {
                        return object;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public String fromString(String string) {
                    if (string == null) {
                        return "";
                    } else {
                        if (string.length() > maxLen) {
                            return string.substring(0, maxLen);
                        } else {
                            return string;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }));

            this.textField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (!newValue) {
                    System.out.println("lost focus");
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                }
            });

            this.textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue.length() > maxLen) {
                    textField.setText(oldValue);
                }
            });

            this.textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent evt) {
                    if (KeyCode.ESCAPE == evt.getCode()) {
                        System.out.println("cancel edit");
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                    if (KeyCode.ENTER == evt.getCode() || KeyCode.TAB == evt.getCode()) {
                        System.out.println("commit edit");
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And you can update your data as below:

```
columnCourse.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
            System.out.println("Commit in Controller ");
            ( e.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    e.getTablePosition().getRow())
            ).set<Name>(e.getNewValue());
        });
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your solution. But I the textfields are not editable. Can you help me.

Comment: I think this is intresting. You don't have change so much in the TextFieldClass. Only put the TextField creation  in a Method, and somethink in the focusListener. But I get not editable cells. Did I miss something ?